# why console.log(window) in js not working on regular visual studio's console?

Tags: javascript, object, window

when I try to implement the below code, and I try to run on chrome. It gives me the answers what I expected. But when I compiled it inside my IDE(visual studio code), it gives me error

```
console.log(window)  // or console.log(this)

/// Above code gives me output on the browser but not on IDE's console  
////


///now again If I try to run the Below code on the IDE's console

function test(){
    return this
} 

console.log(test())  // it gives me the whole window object

console.log(window)  // but not this

console.log(this)   // output is: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you have configured VS Code to run the code through Node.js and not through a remote debug session on a Chrome instance.

Node.js isn't a web browser. It doesn't have a window.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're observing is related to how the `this` keyword behaves in different contexts in JavaScript.

In a browser environment (like when you open the developer console), the global scope (the highest level of scope) is associated with the `window` object. When you use `console.log(this)` in the global scope of a browser environment, it will indeed log the `window` object because `this` refers to the global object, which is `window` in a browser.

However, when you use `console.log(this)` in a JavaScript file running in a Node.js environment or in a module in a Node.js application, you will see an empty object `{}` in the console. This is because in Node.js, the behavior of the `this` keyword is different from the browser. In a Node.js module, `this` refers to the module itself, and it does not automatically point to the global object.

Here's an example to illustrate the difference:

```js
// In a browser environment
console.log(this); // Logs: Window

// In a Node.js module
console.log(this); // Logs: {}
```

So, the behavior of `this` can vary depending on the JavaScript environment you're working in. In the browser, it typically refers to the global `window` object, while in Node.js, it refers to the module or is undefined in strict mode.